# You can scroll sideways on the SE sites dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

What the dropdown normally looks like:

[image]

But if you middle click on the `YOUR COMMUNITIES` bar, you can scroll to the side:

[image]

Middle click scroll  makes the mouse look like this:

[image]

Then you move to scroll. Well middle click to get that mode enabled and then move the mouse to the right.

The CSS:

```
.topbar-dialog.siteSwitcher-dialog.topbar-dialog.siteSwitcher-dialog

{
width: 375px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
min-height:390px;
max-height:390px;
max-width: 390px;
}
```

Changing the width still keeps this gap (exactly 10px).

I haven't found the item in the CSS causing this gap yet. There is an SO [question solving a similar problem though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916697).

---

Computer info:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with latest updates.
Browser: Chrome 38.0.2125.122
JavaScript: 3.28.71.19
Zoom 100% (Same thing happens on 50% and 150%)

Comment: No repro'd on FireFox 33.1, Win XP SP3, though I remember I faced this issue before. Perhaps stating the browser and OS (and maybe zoom level) will help.

Comment: @Andrew Added details.

Comment: It's `.topbar-dialog .site-filter-container` having `width: 100%` and `padding-left: 10px`. The `width: 100%` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Meh, not really answer-worthy, we'll just wait for someone to come along and answer saying that it's been fixed.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome and Win7

Answer (score 3):

I am going to do what Tim Stone said: to answer the question saying that it's fixed. Because it's fixed. I can't do that anymore and doing that makes the browser think you're going to highlight some text. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)