# When I offer a bounty, I don't see upvote notifications

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, notifications, top-bar

When I get an upvote, I get a green bubble:

[image]

These can merge to show total rep across all the sites:

[image]

That shows that I got + 40 and -1 (I downvoted).

This however, doesn't exist:

[image]

You don't get bubbles for - rep.

What this means is, if I offer a bounty for 50 (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243748/you-can-scroll-sideways-on-the-se-sites-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment798599_243748)) and then get 2 upvotes (I did) I don't see the bubble. It would have to display this:

[image]

That's the bounty (-) and upvotes (+). It can't show this.

At the end of it all, because it isn't showing me - rep, I don't see that I have any rep gains here because they cancel out.

Just to be clear, it is only when the bounty and upvotes are on the same question that I don't see upvotes... For example, just here I got the +5 notification for this question being upvoted

**Request:**

Upvotes and downvotes etc still cancel out, and it is only displayed if the over all is +ve, but *bounties are not included in this measure*. Either it would show the -40 or it would just show +10 and completely forget showing the bounty.

Comment: Hmm @Giles but I believe it is a bit different - I'm getting these +5 notifications for all posts except the bounty one, not none for all my posts I believe. I may be mistaken... Also, rather than a [tag:bug] it is [tag:feature-request] and I have a solution to the reason the other one is [tag:status-bydesign]...